# How do I make a super oily surface?

Tags: texturing

Like the patty in this burger :

[image]

As you can see, its looks very wet from the oil, its covered with liquid. How to achieve this?

And here is my patty and its nodes settings, it looks dry:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). You'll need  to use lower roughness and more contrasty lighting.

Comment: I did lower the roughness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment echo: add better lighting. A flat grey background is a recipe for boredom. Try the HDR textures in blender’s own data files as environment textures.

As for the oil, try the clearcoat setting in the Principled shader. It was made for just such a purpose.

Also, nice burger

Comment: I made the clearcoat to the full (1.000) and clearcoat roughness 0.027, it doesnt look too oily https://imgur.com/a/oIitAf8

Comment: I cannot view that link at current. Meanwhile, try the clearcoat roughness at zero. Did you update the world background?

Comment: its the same with clrearcoat roughness at 0, wdym update world background?

Comment: @AgilGA your world background is a flat grey, which will make anything reflective look dull and boring. Use an Environment Texture node to input color into the world, and open one of blender’s HDRIs in its data folders.

Comment: I did actually, https://imgur.com/a/1Upyq4g

Comment: I cannot view that link at current. Can you edit the image into the question?

Comment: wait wait, its res is not 2K

Comment: I changed the world background to the 2K version, and it shows the oil https://imgur.com/a/I7I2Oaw    But there are orange dots as you see in the pic

Comment: I’m glad you’re making progress, but I really can’t view those image links at current.

Comment: why? the links work just fine with my browser